# ckeditor is striping off the our own tag added around <tr>

Tags: ckeditor

ckeditor is striping off  the our own tag added around  Ex : [SomeText] [END-SomeText]. It removed [SomeText] [END-SomeText] and add it before . Is there any solution to leave as is(don't strip off)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my question.
We need to add following configuration.

CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push(/[SomeText]/ig);

CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push(/[END-SomeText]/ig);